# What is the matter about foreach in java6?

Tags: java

```
Map testMap = new HashMap();
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry:testMap.entrySet()){

}
```

it has error tip:"Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Map.Entry"

Would you tell me the reason?

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`testMap` is not of generic type, so `testMap.entrySet` returns objects.

You can correct it like that:

```
Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry:testMap.entrySet()){

}
```

Comment: You should also define your `testMap` to `Map<String, Object> testMap`

Comment: Just ```Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<>();``` is enough

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should declare testMap as

```
Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Answer (score 3):

Your declaration

```
Map testMap = new HashMap();
```

does not mention that testMap.entrySet() should be type `<String, Object>`

The solution is

```
Map<String, Object> testMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

No issues with Java6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with for but with the declaration of your map, you should not use [raw types](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=224).

```
Map testMap = new HashMap();
```

This is more like

```
Map<Object,Object> testMap = new HashMap<Object,Object>();
```

and you are trying to cast this to `Map.Entry<String, Object>`.

The solution for you is to declare properly the object

```
Map<String,Object> testMap = new HashMap<String,Object>();
```